# React : How to do Pagination of Sorted Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, loopbackjs

I am working on React Project . Where I am  fetching data through API and showing it in pagination . Actually I want sorting of data in project but problem is that I have already implemented pagination for data . Currently I am fetching data and showing in pagination but I implemented logic for sorting . When I click on table header data is sorted but all data which are stored in `state` is render in one page . I want sorted data in pagination , I am beginner to React , Could someone please help me how to implement pagination for sorted data . You may also see project flow in given `GIF` file .

[Gif File ( Please Click here to see Project Flow what I want )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw9F2.gif)

***Code***

```
    class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:8001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have direct/indirect access to the api endpoint, you should do your sorting, pagination, filtering, etc there and return the items you want to the front-end. Calls for pagination, etc should be a request to the api for that particular query.

If you're at the point of doing pagination, etc with a server endpoint, you would probably benefit from looking into Redux if you haven't already.

IMO, if you want to stay ahead of the game, learn GraphQL and React Hooks to do away with REST and React Classes respectively.

ETA:

Issues with lifecycle calls aside, when the `componentWillMount` (***this is deprecated - move into the constructor***) it runs the first `get all parties` api, so, when mounting the first page, everything looks fine.

In `btnClick()`, you set `Item` but don't seem to change its value anywhere. I expect this is likely your issue.

Comment: Actually , for Pagination I am using separate REST Call . For sorting I am not able to view data in pagination . Can you please help me out . I am using `Semantic UI React` for sorting but It can working for just current page data not for all

Comment: I'm not sure if you get an update when an answer is edited, so that's what this is for.